# Создать массив в js с группами одинаковых чисел [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Подскажите, как можно создать массив, который будет выводить нечто подобное: То есть, каждая цифра по `n` раз.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
В данном случае, каждая цифра отображена по 5 раз.
```

Я попробовал комбинировать циклы for, while, но пока не удалось.
Это просто стартовый массив. В качестве теста взято число 50.
По итогу должно быть пять единиц, потом пять двоек, потом пять троек и тд, пока их общее число не будет 50

```js
const createArray = (n) => {
  const myArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    myArray[i] = i + 1;
  }
  console.log(myArray)
}
createArray(50)
```

Comment: тут второго цикла не хватает

Comment: Именно так) Вот я не знаю какого(

Comment: То есть  если  n =  10? то каждое число должно водится 10 раз и так от одного до 10?

Comment: Всего должно быть 50 чисел. Первые 5 - это 1, с 6 по 10 - это 2, с 11 по 15 - это 3 и тд. Пусть будет смена идти каждые 5 чисел.

Comment: У вас же потом идёт на снижение. Надо чтобы программа определила середину и пошла на спад? Или как это должно работать?

Comment: Нет, снижения быть не должно. Просто будет пять единиц, потом пять двоек, потом пять троек и тд, пока их общее число не будет 50.

Comment: У меня пока один наводящий вопрос. Если, к примеру, на вход функция примет значение **47**, то какой должен быть результат?

Comment: @EzioMercer Уже дал ответ ниже) 

Перечисление просто останавливается. Если будет 47, тогда в конце будет 41-45 - девятки, а потом 46 и 47 просто две десятки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет лучше, если ф-ия будет возвращать массив, а потом уже выводить его где надо:

```js
const createArray = (n, repeatNum = 5) => {
  const myArray = [];
  let num = 1;
  
  while (myArray.length < n) {
    myArray.push(num);
    
    if (myArray.length % repeatNum === 0) ++num;
  }
  
  return myArray;
}

const createdArray = createArray(52);

console.log(createdArray);
```

Ответ на вопрос из комментария:

```js
const createArray = (n, repeatNum = 5) => {
  const myArray = [];
  let num = 0;
  
  while (myArray.length < n) {
    myArray.push(++num);
    
    if (myArray.length % repeatNum === 0) num = 0;
  }
  
  return myArray;
}

const createdArray = createArray(52, 4);

console.log(createdArray);
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Отличное решение! 

Могу ещё попросить помочь? 

А как теперь создать массив, который будет в себя включать цифры по очереди, но в заданном количестве? 

[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] - это сейчас
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] - вот так нужно

.И тоже самое 
1) Количество повторений - например, 50
2) Количество самих цифр в повторении - например, 4 [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: @СтасМощенский Почти тоже самое, обновил ответ. Буду рад вашему плюсику :)

Comment: Ставлю вам все плюсы, что есть у меня) 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const createArray = (n) => {
  const myArray = [];
  let step = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      step++
    }
    myArray.push(step);
  }
  console.log(myArray);
}
createArray(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const createArray = (n) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3].map(i => new Array(n).fill(i)).flat()

console.log(createArray(5))
```

```js
const createArray = n => new Array(n).fill().map((_, i) => Math.floor(i/5));

console.log(createArray(50));
```

Comment: как-то я не так понял задачу. тогда в вопросе нехватает параметров из чего и сколько нужно набирать. те пока не будет 50 чего?

Comment: Благодарю за ваш пример решения, он так же полезен. 
Там выше уже дали 2 варианта ответа, оба подходят. 
50 - это лишь количество чисел, которые должны быть в массиве. 

А так же, есть ещё один параметр - количество выводов одной и той же цифры.. В ответе, который я пометил галочкой там стоит 5 (кратность). Вот столько раз и будет выводиться каждое число. Пять единиц, пять двоек и так далее. Если там поставить 6, то будет по 6.

Comment: @СтасМощенский но у вас в примере явно порядок стоит определенный у самих чисел. но с такими вводными, как в помеченном ответе еще проще - просто создаем массив и заполняем его от индексов. Обновил ответ